# My co authors backed out after paper acceptance, how to proceed

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review, journals, funding

My paper was accepted in an open access journal, I am the corresponding author, but soon after acceptance my co-authors refused to pay their part of the article processing charges (APC) and sent me the email requesting removal of their names citing inability to pay the APC.

I immediately contacted the academic editor, and informed her of the whole situation, in response the journal clearly stated that they won't waive the AP nor allow me to remove the names of the co-authors, they say that once accepted one cannot add / remove names in accordance with ICMEJ policy.

Now my paper is stuck. Is the journal's stance correct? What should I do in this case? Should I withdraw this paper or should I approach editor in chief to solve this matter?

Comment: Is the journal reputable?

Comment: Are you offering to pay the APC? If not, who is paying the APC? (given that your co-author is not paying)

Comment: Yes i have offered to pay apc but they are not ready to remove names of the co authors

Comment: If you offer to pay the APC, the co-authors get the free authorship, what seem to be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the co authors are not willing to be part of this paper any more can the journal publish names of authors without their consent?

Comment: In case they consented to be part of the paper and acknowledged the final version to be re-submitted /published, it is your co-authors problem ... If they revoke their consent after the paper has been accepted, it is no longer your fault.

Comment: What were your prior arrangements with the co-authors regarding APC charges? Did you have *any*? I am asking the same question as @Allure, but specifically about what did you agree upon BEFORE you have submitted the paper to the journal. You offered to pay APC now, but what was your plan going in into this submission?

Comment: Well the apc charges are quite high 2500 Usd so before submission they agreed to pay their share they are actually five in no! But after acceptance they become non respondent and then upon inquiring they sent me the email i mentioned.!

Comment: Now that you've offered to pay the charge, *what are your coauthors objections to being listed as authors?* You can't know how to proceed without that information.

Comment: "_Yes i have offered to pay apc_" Did you offer to pay the whole amount (USD$2500) or only partial amount? If you'll pay the whole amount, did you tell the co-authors that?

Comment: which country in the world?

Answer (score 36):

There seems to be confusion here:

### Paying part of the APC is neither necessary nor sufficient for being a co-author.

So if the other authors can't pay anything but you can cover the full APC, there is no need to remove them as authors. On the contrary: I assume that they are authors of the paper since they contributed significantly enough and then it would not be ok to remove them from the work.

Moreover:

### The issue of APCs has to be discussed before submission.

There are many possible arrangements (the APC is split, one of the authors pays all, some author has a grant to cover it,…) but the group of authors has to agree. In the case where I was part of some team usually one of the authors offered to pay all of it.

Comment: Also: See this [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/192274/529) related question.

Comment: Is academia the only field where workers pay to work? "When I started, I had to pay Mr Krabs a hundred dollars an hour!"

Comment: Well, they don't pay to do the research and usually APCs are not paid of the own pockets of the researchers but by some budget/grant,…

Comment: @user253751 No.  Lots of kinds of workers pay for their own tools.  Machinists often buy their own (very expensive) measuring devices--though work tools are provided at the factory.   Lots of workers pay for their own work uniforms.

Answer (score 24):

ICMJE (International Committee of Medical Journal Editors) policy actually [has a provision](https://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html) for this specific situation:

> If authors request removal or addition of an author after manuscript
> submission or publication, journal editors should seek an explanation
> and signed statement of agreement for the requested change from all
> listed authors and from the author to be removed or added.

It is technically possible to salvage the paper, but the journal is, IMHO, rightfully concerned about the ethics of the process here, as denying authorship on the basis of refusing to pay APC is highly problematic. I would say that the most ethical thing to do in this situation is for you to decide whether you are still okay with paying APC and if so, keep them as authors. That advice is given under an assumption you have already come to an unambiguous understanding of what happened here.

If not, you would first need to get that shared understanding. Can the paper, take a step back and review your work process. More specifically, your point of view can be described as following to the co-authors ("you" collectively refers to the rest of the co-authors here):

1. We have all agreed to submit our paper to this journal, AND
2. We all knew there would be an APC, AND
3. You have confirmed that you are willing to pay your share of APC, AND
4. You are now refusing to do so.

If any of these points are challenged, all six (?) of you need to agree on why that happened. Maybe they knew there were APCs, but did not expect them to be that high, in which case it is entirely on them. Maybe you did not tell them clearly enough there will be charges, in which case it is mostly on you. Maybe they have agreed to pay, but circumstances have changed (e.g. experiencing troubles dealing with their institution) - in which case it is on them again, but you might be willing to pay. This is what I meant by "decide whether you are still okay with paying APC" - first of all, figure out if you have enough information about the issue or not.

Either way, most of the scenarios converge at this being a monetary/workplace dispute, which is separate from authorship (see [Dirk's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/192330/145124)). Authorship is often reviewed under something collectively known as [moral rights](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/moral_rights):

> In continental Europe, moral rights are “inalienable and cannot be transferred or waived.”

In other words, you might have been scammed out of two grand - which you **need** to figure out and dispute accordingly with them and, possibly, institutions involved. But all that does not make it right to revoke the authorship UNLESS they are now **strongly** objecting to be associated with the paper at all, in which case you badly need a clarification as well.

The entire situation sounds like a huge breach of work ethics - from your description, they are at fault, but we do not see the other side of the story here (e.g. do you have a clear confirmation, in writing, that they have earlier agreed to paying these charges?).

Comment: Fully agree with this superb comment. Yet, it is questionable whether a consensus might be achieved with the "other side".

Comment: " I would say that the most ethical thing to do in this situation is for you to decide whether you are still okay with paying APC and if so, keep them as authors" - this is potentially dangerous given OP's apparent lack of understanding about what's going on. It's critical that the OP come to an agreement with coauthors over what comes next, not just pay the charges and keep them on if they're asking to be removed.

Comment: Its true , first they breached the committment because it was decided before submission that they will contribute for apc , secondly, now they are asking to be removed, what if i pay apc , but after publication they ask editor for retraction. ? I dont know why journal is unable to understand this point. This is complicating things!

Comment: @PG You keep changing the subject and not responding to questions for clarification here. Your situation is very unclear based on what you've written here, so it's no wonder the journal isn't understanding. Please clarify so that we can help you communicate with the journal. It seems like *you or your coauthors* are complicating things, not the journal.

Comment: @P G Find this rather confusing.  Co-authors knew there was APC.  Presumably contributed time, effort, and (possibly) money to the work.  Had the work accepted.  And then asked to be removed?  Feels like there must be something not included like:  Bad journal, Worse journal than hoped for, Shame in research results?  Are the co-authors adamant about being removed, or just hoping you'll pay and foot the bill?

Comment: @BryanKrause I agree. To me, there are two possible courses of action: if what has happened is truly unclear, take a step back to first figure it out, or, if it is clear that co-authors have, indeed, agreed to pay their share of APC and then bailed, it becomes a financial/workplace issue, possible with the institution involvement. If OP's responses are representative of their communication with the co-authors, clarification is much needed. I will add an edit correspondingly, thank you.

Comment: I have added several clarifications - unfortunately, the changes ended up being substantial, so I apologize to the voters here. If that was out of line, I will delete the answer and post it anew.  I believe it has been overall improved, however.

Comment: I would like to clarify point by point 1.authors were aware from day 1 that they have to pay Apc. 2.Apc charges of 2500 were also clear to them before submission 3. Their role was in formal analysis and provision of resources not in write up. 4.we agreeably submitted to this journal 5. My concern is that even if i keep them on paper and I make payment and later after payment, they write to the journal for removal of thier names ?

Comment: Your question reads: ` Is the journal's stance correct?` Yes, yes it is. Please reach an internal agreement between yourself and co-authors first, the journal could not possibly be responsible for that. I hope "we agreeably submitted to this journal" means "all authors affirmatively confirmed the decision to submit the paper as it was written" (is that so?).

Comment: Ultimately, write to your co-authors and demand that they either 1) Provide a written request for their names to be removed from the paper along with clarification for the editorial office (they have presumably agreed on the paper and all the prior corrections, after all!) or 2) Confirm (in writing!) that they do not object that you pay the APC and the paper is published in its current state. If they decide to write to the journal even after that, that is on them and you have no control over it. Either way, raise the issue with your institution(s) and/or never work with these people again.

Comment: They did provide the written request for names removal and I shared it with the assistant editor but then too she is insisting on adding their names!

Comment: @PG Well, yeah, authors are supposed to be determined based on contribution to the paper, not based on whether they're willing to pay. Either you included them unethically in the beginning, or are removing them unethically now, or there is a very special case here that **you still are not communicating properly**. I still don't know whether this is mostly a language barrier or whether you have no idea how academic publishing works, and I think it's very dangerous to proceed without resolving what's going on.

Comment: @PG **Now that you are paying all the publishing costs, have you asked your coauthors if they want their names back on the paper?** If you asked, did the coauthors refuse? If they refused, why did they refuse?

Comment: @PG Do their objections extend beyond simply the cost-sharing?  Do your co-authors not support your conclusions? Are they suspicious of you for some type of academic fraud or other malfeasance? In other words, are they suspicious that your data is overly "massaged" or created out of "thin air"?  Did you submit them as a corresponding author, perhaps providing a signature on their behalf, without verifying that they authorized it?

Comment: @mpag, the issue is more work ethics related than such gross unethical practices which you mentioned.what i have understood from their message is that they are not willing to pay their share of Apc and simply think that withdrawal of names might spare them from payment. Because in their email they just mentioned inability to pay and request for removal of thier name.

Answer (score 9):

If I'm understanding your comments right, this happened:

- You submitted the paper to an open access journal with your co-authors' agreement & with the understanding that the APC will be split between authors.
- Your paper is accepted. The journal sends you an invoice for the APC.
- Your co-authors refuse to pay the APC and want to withdraw their name from the article.
- The journal does not let you remove names from the paper, and your paper is in limbo as a result.

If this description is accurate, then this is a dispute between the authors and not the journal's concern. From the journal's perspective, they can't just waive the APC without reason, and they can't just let you remove an author's name either. This is because authorship rules generally say that everyone who contributed substantially to the paper should be an author ([example](https://provost.yale.edu/policies/academic-integrity/guidance-authorship-scholarly-or-scientific-publications)). The journal can no more publish your paper without your co-authors' names than you can submit it without your co-authors' names.

So: discuss with co-authors. First figure out exactly what the problem is - it's not clear what the co-authors' objections are. Then figure out what to do. If your description (co-authors didn't want co-authorship because they didn't want to pay the APC) is correct, then the obvious result is that they will no longer object since you are paying the entire APC, and the journal can publish it. Alternatively they could be refusing co-authorship even though you are paying the entire APC, because they have lost faith in the manuscript for some reason. If this is indeed the case, you could submit signed documents from the co-authors verifying this to the journal.

Either way, do not email the journal until you have resolved the problem. It really is not something for them to solve.

Comment: Thanks, for the correct understanding, I have also reached to this conclusion that I need to resolve this on the authors level.